# Why can a class load another class' private inner class?

Tags: java

I have

```
class A {
    private static class B {
        B() {
        }
    }
}
```

though B is private I load A$B.class from another class without a problem. Why is that allowed?

```
class C {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(Class.forName("A$B").newInstance());
    }
}
```

**output**

```
A$B@affc70
```

**UPDATE**

I understand that the restriction for loading any classes is raised intentionally, but there must be a reasonable explanation why.

Note that package private B{} constructor there is on purpose. If I remove it I will get

java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class B can not access a member of class A$B with modifiers "private"

Comment: language access control keywords are there for development efficiency and safety, they are not supposed to and do not in fact have any additional access segregation role at runtime

Comment: @bobah: that's not *entirely* true. The Java security mechanism (think security manager) actually *depends* on some of the private fields *staying* private. That's why many reflection "tricks" don't work with an active security manager.

Comment: Note that it is possible to recreate this situation without using reflection by hand-crafting C.class to use the normal byte code for new A$B().

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This behaviour is compliant with [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20java.lang.ClassLoader%29):

> Note that this method does not check whether the requested class is accessible to its caller.

In other words, `forName` can access non accessible classes and won't throw an `IllegalAccessExcessException`. And because the constructor is package private, i.e. (I assume) accessible from your calling location, `newInstance` does not throw any exceptions either.

If the constructor were not accessible (either because you move it to another package or you make it private), `newInstance` would throw an exception.

Regarding your update, if you remove the constructor, you will be calling the default constructor which will have the same access as the class, in this case private (cf [JLS 8.8.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.3): *if the class is declared private, then the default constructor is implicitly given the access modifier private*).

Comment: While this is better than the answer with the high vote count, it is still not completely true. If you move C to another package and make the constructor public, you will still get an IllegalAccessException on instantiation. Further, the same package situation can be replicated by crafting C.class to use normal byte-code commands instead of reflection.

Comment: @HendrikBrummermann Fair point and the javadoc for `newInstance`: *IllegalAccessException - if the **class** or its nullary constructor is not accessible.* (emphasis mine) so I don't think my answer is correct.

Answer (score 12):

The class loader [may load any class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20java.lang.ClassLoader%29), but the access rules are enforced on instantiation.

So why is your code able to instantiate the class?

Inner classes are a big hack at the byte code level because they were implemented to be byte-code compatible with Java 1.0.

So this private inner class at the source code level is in fact package-protected at byte code level. You can verify that by moving class C into another package and making the constructor of B public:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessException: 
Class something.C can not access a member of class A$B with modifiers "public"
```

Reflection does allow to override access rules by using setAccessible(), but this is not the case here.

Answer (score 3):

Reflection is commonly used by programs which require the ability to **examine or modify the runtime behaviour of applications** running in the Java virtual machine.

It's **a tool that lets one break some rules**, one can throw it over his foot or use it properly.

Reflection provides a mechanism for accessing information about classes through means which are usually not available by regular interaction between classes and objects.

> One of such is allowing access to private fields from outside classes
>   and objects.

However, both `getDeclaredField()` and `setAccessible()` are actually checked by the security manager and will throw an exception when your code is not allowed to do this. Many reflection tricks may not work with an active security manager.

Answer (score 3):

While reflections is a good comparison, the class loader goes beyond what the reflection library can do.  For example, a class loader can create classes, which you can't do with reflections. It can also

- trigger the creation of enum instances.
- give you a reference to a class before it has been initialised.
- "override" a class in a parent class loader.
- trigger classes to unload when it is unloaded.
- give you the byte code for a classes, giving you the raw implementation details.
- give you a stream for non-class resources in the class path.

Like reflections, it can load a class with private members and it would be rather pointless if it couldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Using reflection Even you can change the modifiers

```
class MyClass{
private int value;
}

Field value = MyClass.class.getDeclaredField("value");
value.setAccessible(true);
```

Comment: You can't change the modifiers, you can ignore them which is what setAccessible(true) does.